# Leaflet geojson layer with customized divIcon for each feature

Tags: svg, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to set a different divIcon for each point on a leaflet geoJson layer. I have tried everything under the sun but it just doesn't work for me. This is what I'm doing

```
geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var smallIcon = L.DivIcon.extend({
      options: {
        iconSize: [27, 27],
        html: "<div>" + feature.properties.FEATURE_STYLE.SVG_ELEMENT + "</div>"
      }
    });
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: new smallIcon()});
  },      
  style: getLayerStyle,
  onEachFeature: setFeatureProperties,
});
geoJsonLayer.addTo(baseMap);
```

feature.properties.FEATURE_STYLE.SVG_ELEMENT is an html `<svg>` containing the icon.

The icons are displayed ok, but **every feature display the same icon**.

I've also tried doing the following:

1. using L.Icon with different .png in iconUrl for each feature
2. using L.circleMarker with different colors for each feature

They both works as expected (different color / icon per feature). But I can't seem to get the divIcon to display differently for each feature.

Anyone have idea why this is the case?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

[This is what **feature.properties.FEATURE_STYLE.SVG_ELEMENT** looks like](https://pastebin.com/aC2nvEpn)

Comment: Please include a small code (like your SVG) that still reproduces the issue, in the body of your question. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the svg that I'm using is in the pastebin link above: "This is what feature.properties.FEATURE_STYLE.SVG_ELEMENT looks like". It's too long for me to include in a code tag. Thanks.

Comment: Consider refactoring your SVG to get the minimum that still reproduces your issue. I am sure you might discover things by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Your code to instantiate a new `L.divIcon` is more complicated than really necessary, but it works, not considering the SVG part:

https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/236/

That being said, please note that:

- [`style`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-style) option is used for vector layers. Therefore in the case of `Point` features that are rendered as `L.divIcon`'s, it is not used.
- [`onEachFeature`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-oneachfeature) option is applied *after* the [`pointToLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-pointtolayer) one, because the latter is needed to create the `layer` that is fed to `onEachFeature`. Therefore if you build the `feature.properties.FEATURE_STYLE.SVG_ELEMENT` in there (as the name of your function `setFeatureProperties` suggests), it is too late.

If you need further help, you would very probably need to share more code, e.g. the style and onEachFeature options, and some sample data, in particular with `feature.properties.FEATURE_STYLE.SVG_ELEMENT`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Style is just setting default size, color, opacity in case we're not using icons as marker. and we use onEachFeature to bind popup and tooltip, it does not control any marker in there. I've updated an example to the SVG_ELEMENT above. The problem is that when I use L.icon and pass a .png image in, it works fine. But L.divIcon updates every marker already on the map.